# Puppet - Don't stop manifest execution if a module fails

Tags: puppet

I'm having some trouble understanding one of many Puppet logic mechanisms : the module failing scenario.

I have multiple modules doing various things on a set of differences nodes and I want to implement the following scenario :

1. deploy all modules for specified nodes
2. if a module execution fails, only fail this module but keep applying other modules

I wrote something along these lines in my test module (`yum`) :

`init.pp` :

```
class yum {
    case $operatingsystem { 
        /(RedHat|CentOS)/ : { include yum:config }
        default:            { include yum:fail }
    }
}

class yum::config {
    debug("[${fqdn}] Deploying yum.conf file")
    #DEPLOY YUM.CONF CODE
}

class yum:fail {
    fail("[${fqdn}] This module is only for RedHat or CentOS")
}
```

And in my `site.pp` manifest :

```
node 'redhat', 'centos', 'debian' {
    include yum
    include motd
}
```

The problem is, if the `operatingsystem` case is not satisfied by a given node (`debian` in this instance), it will fail all consecutive modules (`motd` will NOT be applied).

So the question is : what am I doing wrong in this case ?

PS: Keep in mind that I'm still in the process of learning Puppet best practices and, as such, I am not pretending my code is spotless.

Comment: Why are you explicitly doing a fail()?  What benefit do you think that gives you?  If you use fail(), then puppet is going to **fail**.  Perhaps what you really need to do is log a warning()/notice()?

Answer (score 1):

Silly me. It seems indeed that, considering my module structure, I just have to do nothing once we are in the child class `yum::fail` (maybe just put an `info` and/or `debug` message). No need to fail it explicitly.